# Pandas column value arrangement

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I have a data about google play statistic and the Insatalls column values make me failed.It is like 10.000+ and I want to get rid of "+" for all values. What can I do ? Is there any pandas trick ?

Answer (score 2):

Use this code to strip '+' on right ends

```
df['Installs'] = df['Installs'].str.rstrip('+')
```

Comment: I have a problem with this code. KeyError: 'Installs'                                                        .

""""""sorted_by_Installs = data.sort_values(by = "Installs",ascending = False, na_position='first')"""""""   This code works so there is no problem with Installs

Comment: The column name must be same as in the dataframe. If it is `Insatalls`, use that.

Comment: My bad. In the dataframe it is Installs and I wrote here Insatalls.But  the problem stems from Kaggle it works on spyder thank you.

Comment: Post the error as edit to your original post @J.Doe

Answer (score 0):

```
df['Installs'] = df['Installs'].apply(lambda x: x.rstrip('+'))
```

Comment: While this may answer the question, please consider adding some context to explain how it works.